# Instant search in rails doesn't display the correct output

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, search

I am coding a small app with a search that enables a user to find products. User can find products by `name` and can filter products by `price` & `weight` (the output is then a list of product in descending order by price or weight). I am using the `gem pg-search` on my product model :

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  include PgSearch
  pg_search_scope :search,
  :against => [:name],
  :using => {:tsearch => {:prefix => true} }
```

This is my index method in ProductController :

```
def index
    if params[:content].present? && (params[:price] == "1")
      @products = Product.search(params[:content]).order(price: :desc)
      respond_to do |format|
        format.js {}
        format.html{ render :index }
      end
    elsif params[:content].present? && (params[:weight] == "1")
      @products = Product.search(params[:content]).order(weight: :desc)
      respond_to do |format|
        format.js {}
        format.html{ render :index }
      end
    elsif params[:content].present?
      @products = Product.search(params[:content])
      respond_to do |format|
        format.js {}
        format.html{ render :index }
      end
    elsif params[:price] == "1"
      @products = Product.all.order(price: :desc)
      respond_to do |format|
        format.js {}
        format.html{ render :index }
      end
    elsif params[:weight] == "1"
      @products = Product.all.order(weight: :desc)
      # binding.pry
      respond_to do |format|
        format.js {}
        format.html{ render :index }
      end
    else
      @products = Product.all
      # binding.pry
    end
  end
```

this is the partial that renders the results of the product search :

```
<div id="js-product-row">
  <%if @products.empty?%>
    <p>
      <strong>Il n'y a pas encore de produit sur le site</strong>
    </p>
 <%else%>
    <% @products.each do |product| %>
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-body">
          <div class="container-fluid">
             <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-2">
                <%= image_tag product.picture.url(:medium)%>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-offset-3 col-md-3">
                <p><strong>
                  <%= product.description %>
                </strong></p>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-4">
                <strong>
                  <%= product.price %> €
                </strong>
                <strong>
                  <%= product.weight %> Kg
                </strong>
                <div>
                  <%= link_to "En savoir plus", product_path(product) %>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
         </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  <% end -%>
<% end -%>
```

and this is the js file to update the view without reloading the page :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#js-product-row').html("<%= escape_javascript(render 'products')%>");
});
```

when I am debugging in the console, @products always gives me an array with exactly what I want in it, in the right order, so it seems that the back end logic is alright. But everytime I search for something or I activate a filter, the rendered output isn't right : info concerning the correct instance (the one actually in the `@products` array) is displayed twice, alongside with other products that are not in `@products`. I don't understand why this is happening.

Comment: instead of `format.js {}` may be you'd give a try to `format.js`

Comment: I couldn't understand why you used `<% end -%>` instead of `<% end %>`

Comment: doesnt change anything

Comment: I'm really confused by that Javascript function.  It looks like when the page is loaded it renders the `_products` - is this using turbolinks at all (not something I'm familiar with)?  Can you perhaps expand on what the JS is doing there please?

Comment: It does exactly what you say

Comment: Hmm, OK then - so why aren't you rendering this out in the `index.html.erb` view using just `render "products"`?  Or if you are, is that possibly the cause of the duplication?  It doesn't look (to my naive eyes) like it's doing something with turbolinks, from looking at the turbolinks README.  

I'm not sure I see the point in rendering HTML in JS when you can render it in the view, though there may obviously factors I'm unaware of in your codebase.

Answer (score 0):

Try using .replaceWith rather than .html otherwise remove `<div id="js-product-row">` from the partial.

e.g:

```
$('#js-product-row').replaceWith("<%= j(render 'products') %>");
```

What I'm guess is happening is that you have

```
<div id="js-product-row">
...
</div>
```

Then you search which adds the html like so:

```
<div id="js-product-row">
   <div id="js-product-row">
    ...
   </div>
 </div>
```

Running again would give something like this (e.g. double results):

```
 <div id="js-product-row">
   <div id="js-product-row">
    ...
   </div>
   <div id="js-product-row">
    ...
   </div>
 </div>
```

**Bonus Update:**

As a side note you can DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself) up your controller like so:

```
def index
  @products = Product
  if params[:content].present?
    @products = @products.search(params[:content])
  end
  if params[:price] == "1"
    @products = @products.order(price: :desc)
  elsif params[:weight] == "1"
    @products = @products.order(weight: :desc)
  end
  @products = @products.all
  format.js
  format.html
end
```